# Deserialize a changing JSON

Tags: c#, json

**EDIT 1:** Still hasn't been resolved ...

**EDIT 2:** Finally resolved! See answer below.

I want to deserialize a changing JSON in C#. With that, creating classes for it is impossible as I can't create classes for every changing piece. The objects are those who are changing, like this:

Unchanged JSON:

```
{
  "Class 1": {
    "Blablabla": {
       "ExampleValue1": "Example Value",
       "ExampleValue2": 500
  },
    "Blablabla-Blablabla": {
       "ExampleValue1": "Example Value",
       "ExampleValue2": 1000
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "Class 1": {
    "Blablabla-Changed-Blablabla": {
       "ExampleValue1": "Changed Example Value",
       "ExampleValue2": 750
  },
    "Blablabla-Blablabla-Changed-Blablabla": {
       "ExampleValue1": "Changed Example Value",
       "ExampleValue2": 1125
}
```

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Is the set of incoming formats known, or it's arbitrary ?

Comment: @mkArtak Arbitrary, because there are changing filenames. I can't directly access them via names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) class from `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`.

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
JToken class1 = token.SelectToken("Class1");
```

Note that if you want to use spaces in fieldnames you need to use the following [`JSONPath`](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) notation to use the `SelectToken` method.

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
JToken class1 = token.SelectToken("['Class 1']")
```

---

You can also dynamicly access the members and children of the `JToken`. For example if you want to dynamicly print the structue you can do the following

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
PrintChildren(token);

private void PrintChildren(JToken item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Path);
    foreach(var child in item.Children())
    {
        PrintChildren(child);
    }
}
```

---

You could also deserialize your json into a `dynamic`.

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Or

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
```

Comment: The thing is, it should enumerate them in a list, and be directly accessable, not via names (because these class names are filenames that also change)

Comment: @danielk I've added an example how you can access the properties without knowing their names.

Comment: Yes, but it's too complicated as I have to loop through till the end. Isn't there an easier way to do that?

Comment: @danielk It depends on what you want to do. I do not really know what the goal is.

Comment: Here is the plan:

1. Download the JSON file
2. Deserialize the JSON file
3. For each object get the stuff from them then do something with it

Comment: The `dynamic`-keyword still doesn't help, especially because I can't access anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it. After figuring & thinking, I managed to resolve the issue. I loop through the dynamic object, convert the JProperty objects to a class and done!